# How to translate this code from muPAD to Python?

Tags: python, translation, mupad

I hope if someone knows how to express the following Mupad code in Python:

```
for n from 1 to 6 do
 M:= matrix([[B(k,j) $ k = 0..n] $ j = 0..n]);
 C:=matrix([c(j)$ j = 0..n]);
 A:=linalg::matlinsolve(M, C);P:=sum(A[j+1]*x^j, j = 0..n);plot(P,fx, x =-1..1);
end_for:
```

Comment: That looks like very complicated piece of code. It's been squashed down to take very little space and doesn't use descriptive variables. Why do you need this translated?

Comment: Indeed, this is part of a method of Least Squares approximation for a function, currently I'm trying to construct a different kind of code, because this one is hard to read, thanks @Bluenix

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand this code at all, but here's some tips...

For-loops in Python look like this (this is [Python shell](https://www.python.org/shell/)):

```py
>>> for i in range(1, 6+1):
...     print(i)
...
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Not knowing Mupad I am unsure if `for n from 1 to 6 do` means:

> a) 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 (`range(0, 6)`)
>
> b) 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 (`range(0, 6+1)`)
>
> c) 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 (`range(1, 6+1)`)

I see that there's references of "matrix", for that see the commonly used library [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) and their documentation on [numpy.matrix](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html). It already has a lot of methods for your simplicity.

Your best option is probably to search up the NumPy alternative rather than do the work with this piece of code.